# Killing an specified executable path with vbscript

Tags: batch-file, cmd, vbscript, wmic

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim fso,oShell,file
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "Taskkill /F /IM mysqld.exe",0,True  

file = "C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe"
If fso.FileExists(file) Then
    fso.DeleteFile file
End If
Set oShell = Nothing 
Set fso = Nothing
```

I tried killing the mysqld.exe from the specified directory with the following cmd
oShell.run "WMIC PROCESS WHERE "ExecutablePath like 'C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe'" DELETE but getting an error, even running the wmic cmd on cmd.exe im getting an error..
There are multiple processes mysqld.exe running in other directories, How can i kill & delete just one from a specified path?

Answer (score 1):

Typing commands or simulating typing commands is not programming.

Help is available for these objects from the command line interface.

```
wmic path Win32_Process get /?
```

and

```
wmic path Win32_Process call /?
```

and if the object had writable properties

```
wmic path Win32_Process set /?
```

Anything commands can do programs can also do.

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process")

For Each objItem in colItems
    'msgbox objItem.name & " " & objItem.CommandLine
    If LCase(objItem.name) = "notepad.exe" then 
        If Msgbox("Close Notepad", 33, "Program Closer") = 1 then
            objItem.terminate
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: the taskkill was an easier method. the problem is how can i specify the path to the executable that i want to kill?..

Comment: It is not a programing question but how do I type a user command. See `wmic /?`.

Comment: @datarocker Disk pizza is an easier method to eat, but I prefer make my own pizza in home by myself. Is not about how easier it is, there are preferences, it is  personal